# What is in utf8mb4 that is not in utf8 in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, utf8mb4

Can't seem to find any resources online that state what languages/characters are in MySQL's utf8mb4 (4 byte utf8) that are not in utf8 (3 byte UTF8).

Can someone please explain what additional language/character support comes with utf8mb4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130511134852/http://status.net/open-source/issues/2833), [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) all characters that were outside the Basic Multilinguan Plane were truncated with the old `utf8` type in MySQL.

Basically with `utf8mb4` you should be able to support even the [Supplementary Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29#Supplementary_Multilingual_Plane) and even what's further.

Comment: Isn't it `mb4` instead of `m4`?